# Error When Cross Compiling gnutls

Tags: linux, compilation, cross-compiling, mips64

I am trying to cross compile gnutls. Gnutls depends on libnettle. I was able to cross compile libnettle, however, when trying to cross compile gnutls, I encounter an error during configure:

```
configure: error:  Libnettle 2.2 was not found.
```

The libnettle version I cross compiled was 2.2.

Command to configure is:

```
./configure --host=mips --prefix=/home/tom/lib/gnutls-3.0.3 CC=/crosstools/mips-gcc CXX=/crosstools/mips-g++ --enable-shared --with-libnettle-prefix=/home/tom/lib/nettle-2.2
```

I have also tried:
configure with `LDFLAGS="-L/home/tom/lib/nettle-2.2"` with no luck.

The libs are installed in /home/tom/lib/nettle-2.2/lib.  I have also tried this directory.  For some reason libnettle is not getting detected. Anyone know why?

Comment: Try `LFLAGS` instead and look in the output of `configure` (config.log). What fails?

Comment: but what's in config.log? It should have what test program was compiled to detect libnettle and what made it fail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Alex.  I have tried with LFLAGS instead, and encounter the same thing.

configure:8351: checking for libnettle
configure:8370: /crosstoolsmips64/bin/mips-gcc -std=
gnu99 -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  -lnettle -lhogweed -lgmp >&5
conftest.c:36:24: nettle/gcm.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c: In function `main':
conftest.c:40: warning: implicit declaration of function `gcm_set_iv'
configure:8370: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
configure:8380: result: no
configure:8406: error: 
  ***
  *** Libnettle 2.2 was not found.

Comment: As you can see it can't even compile, because it doesn't find the headers. Maybe it doesn't respect `--with-libnettle-prefix` setting or it's not the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508851/how-to-compile-gnutls) and my own personal experience, gnutls needs to see both libnettle and libhogweed in order to get past this check.  A nettle build will build both, but only if you also have [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) libraries on the system as well.

Here are some steps to perform to get this working:

1. Check your /home/tom/lib/nettle-2.2/lib directory and ensure that you have both libnettle.so and libhogweed.so.
2. If you don't have libhogweed.so, you will have to rebuild nettle with [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).  Your distro may have a gmp-devel package that will install the necessary GMP library (mine did, so I didn't try building GMP from source)
3. You should then be able to build gnutls, or at the very least, get past the check for libnettle.