# No NETTLE when building gnutls-3.2.18

Tags: makefile, configure, gnutls

I'm getting

```html
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for NETTLE... no
configure: error: 
  ***
  *** Libnettle 2.7.1 was not found. Note that this version of gnutls doesn't support nettle 3.0.
```

when trying to build gnutls.

having found [How to compile GnuTLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508851/how-to-compile-gnutls) I downloaded both gmp-6.0.0 and nettle-2.7.1 and built them with

./configure --prefix=/opt/nxweblibs  LDFLAGS="-L/opt/nxweblibs/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/nxweblibs/include"

and then tried to build gnutls again with same flags but again got error. Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: well, in my case, it's because **there're Chinese/multi-bytes characters in the path name**. I'm building OpenWRT 14.07, it downloaded gmp-6.0.0 nettle-2.7.1 gnutls-3.3.10 automatically and trying to build, and then it ended with exactly same error as yours. Well, I want to ask this question in openwrt forum (English forum) with error logs, so I delete Chinese characters in the path and build again, surprise, it passed